# R: Find first occurence of value for each day

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame with datetimes and values (between 0 and 1) and i would like to find the **first occurence** of value=1 **per day**.

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = '
Datetime                   Value
"2016-12-01 23:45:00"      0
"2016-12-01 23:50:00"      1
"2016-12-02 00:05:00"      1
"2016-12-02 00:10:00"      0
"2016-12-03 04:10:00"      0
"2016-12-03 04:15:00"      0
"2016-12-04 12:10:00"      1
"2016-12-04 12:15:00"      1
')
df$Datetime <- as.POSIXct(df$Datetime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")
View(df)
```

What i would like to have is:

```
2016-12-01 23:50:00      1
2016-12-02 00:05:00      1
2016-12-04 12:10:00      1
```

I tried to solve the problem with match() and aggregate() but had no luck so far. Furthermore i was able to solve the problem with a for loop but it is was a) very slow and b) probably not the way it is meant to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df[!duplicated(paste0(as.Date(df$Datetime), df$Value)) & df$Value == 1, ]
#              Datetime Value
# 2 2016-12-01 23:50:00     1
# 3 2016-12-02 00:05:00     1
# 7 2016-12-04 12:10:00     1
```

---

Explanation:

Create date (`as.Date`) - Value combinations using `paste0`. Create a logical vector indicating which of the combinations that are not (`!`) duplicates of preceeding elements (`duplicated`), and combine it with a test if 'Value' is 1 (`& df$Value == 1`).

Answer (score 5):

An alternative with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
 #group
 group_by(as.Date(Datetime)) %>%
 #select only those where value equals 1
 filter(Value == 1) %>%
 #get only the first row
 slice(1) %>%
 #ungroup
 ungroup %>%
 #select columns
 select(Datetime, Value)
```

Ouput:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
             Datetime Value
               <time> <int>
1 2016-12-01 23:50:00     1
2 2016-12-02 00:05:00     1
3 2016-12-04 12:10:00     1
```

Or as per @Akrun 's comment:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Date = as.Date(Datetime)) %>% 
  slice(which(Value==1)[1])
```

Comment: I think one step could be reduced with `df %>%group_by(Date = as.Date(Datetime)) %>% slice(which(Value==1)[1])`

Comment: Thanks a lot @akrun . Nice one!

Answer (score 4):

We can separate out all of the rows with `Value==1`.  Of course,  the first one of these should be included. After the first one, we include a row only if the day is unequal to the day for the previous row with Value==1.

```
Ones = df[df$Value == 1,]
DayChange = c(1, which(diff(as.Date(Ones$Datetime)) > 0)+1)
Ones[DayChange,]
             Datetime Value
2 2016-12-01 23:50:00     1
3 2016-12-02 00:05:00     1
7 2016-12-04 12:10:00     1
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option using `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by converting 'Datetime' to `Date`, specifying the 'i' as `Value==1`, we get the index of first occurrence of 1 (`.I[1]`), and use that to subset the rows

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[Value==1, .I[1], .(as.Date(Datetime))]$V1]
#              Datetime Value
#1: 2016-12-01 23:50:00     1
#2: 2016-12-02 00:05:00     1
#3: 2016-12-04 12:10:00     1
```